# Close was never specifically called when using ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I am having issue with android content provider with loadermanager. I am using LoaderManager to load my CursorLoader from ContentProvider and ContentProvider is calling my sqlite class.
In Sqlite class, I am calling sql query and returning cursor, not closing cursor or database.
As I understood, that's how it is supposed to work (and it doesn't work when I close cursor/db), but after second visit in activity, I am getting this exception about database not being closed. It must be something stupid.

I am calling initLoader of LoaderManager in my onActivityCreated of my fragment.

Here is my query method in ContentProvider:

```
public synchronized Cursor query(final Uri uri, final String[] projection, final String selection, final String[] selectionArgs, final String sortOrder) {
    final SongDbHandler songDbHandler = AbstractActivity.getLocalService(getContext()).getDbHandler();
    String order = " ";
    if ("author".equals(sortOrder)) {
        order = Constants.ORDER_AUTHOR;
    } else if ("song".equals(sortOrder)) {
        order = Constants.ORDER_SONG;
    }
    System.out.println("getAllSongs");
    final Cursor cursor = songDbHandler.getAllSongs(order);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

Here is my code in sqlite class (singleton SQLiteOpenHelper subclass):

```
public Cursor getAllSongs(String order) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor;
    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "";
        sql += "select " + Constants.AUTHOR_SELECT_COLUMNS + ", " + Constants.SONG_SELECT_COLUMNS + ", " + Constants.GLOBAL_ID;
        sql += " from " + Constants.SONG_TABLE_NAME + ", " + Constants.AUTHOR_TABLE_NAME + " ";
        sql += " where " + Constants.SONG_TABLE_NAME + "." + Constants.AUTHOR_FK + " = " + Constants.AUTHOR_TABLE_NAME + "." + Constants.AUTHOR_ID + " AND  " + Constants.SONG_TABLE_NAME + "."
                + Constants.SONG_SOURCE_TYPE + " = " + Constants.AUTHOR_TABLE_NAME + "." + Constants.AUTHOR_SOURCE_TYPE;
        // sql += " order by " + Constants.AUTHOR_TABLE_NAME + "." +
        // Constants.AUTHOR_NAME + COLLATE;
        sql += order;
        // sql += " limit 20 ";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
        return cursor;
    } finally {
        //closeQuietly(db);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
Here is my LoaderManager callback:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle bundle) {
    return (Loader<Cursor>) new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SongContentProvider.getLocalProviderUri(), null, null, null, bundle.getString("order"));
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor songs) {
    updateData(songs);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Edit2:

```
private void updateData(Cursor songs) {
    adapter.swapCursor(songs);
    if (songs == null || songs.getCount() == 0) {
        vysledky.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vysledkyMsg.setText(getString(R.string.no_results));
        vysledkyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        vysledky.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vysledkyMsg.setText(getString(R.string.progress_loading_content));
        vysledkyMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is with your implementation of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`(you do not call swapCursor of adapter or do not close the cursor) not with this code

Comment: Thanks, I edited post and added my code with LoaderCallbacks. I am using swapCursor there. Where should I close cursor?

Comment: what is updateData doing ... if you are using adapter you should call only `adapter.swapCursor(songs);` in `onLoadFinished` ... thats why i love ContentProviders ... if you are not using adapter(single row without Adapter/ListView) then close songs cursor at the end of updateData

Comment: Edited again - I'm just showing information if there are no results.

Comment: then it should be no problem here ... do not use SongDbHandler  outside the ContentProvide implementation create only one instance of this class in onCreate of ContentProvider ... (to force you to not use it outside CP make SongDbHandler inner static class of CP) ...

Comment: Right now SongDbHandler is basically my database layer with many methods like getAllSongs, but they mostly return POJO's and close cursor/database before returning. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: `Do you think that could be the problem?` No, i'm guessing that it could be a problem ... you just forgot to close one of the cursor somehere ...

Comment: Yes, but I can't find where. If I understand correctly, I don't close cursor when ContentProvider/LoaderManager is used as it does for himself and there are no calls to db layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time I finally fixed everything. Error was originally caused, because my db class wasn't singleton and every call created new database connection instance, so old reference was lost and ContentProvder couldn't close it. Basically I came to this:

- Db class as singleton, it removed most of my issues.
- I am closing cursor in onPause and before every restartLoader call.

Now I have 3 concurrent contentloaders in 3 fragments and they are working fine.